# Cannot upload file to Amazon S3 using Boto

Tags: python-2.7, heroku, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto

I'm using Flask / Heroku and the Boto library. I want the uploaded file to be saved in my S3...

```
@app.route("/step3/", methods = ["GET", "POST"])
def step3():
    if request.method == "GET":
        return render_template("step3.html")
    else:
        file = request.files['resume']
        if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            k = Key(S3_BUCKET)
            k.key = "TEST"
            k.set_contents_from_filename(file)
            return redirect(url_for("preview"))
```

but the following gives me the following...

```
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, FileStorage found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To write it you need to change your file as a String, that means you need to read it after it has been open.